# javascript menu redfin scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, jquery-animate

I have a very long webpage with multiple anchor tags that can be linked to from a top navigation bar.  The bar fixes itself at the top of the screen as the user scrolls.  I would like to have a small icon that moves horizontally along the navigation as the user scrolls down the page (indicating where you are)...  The functionality I am looking for is on redfin.com at the following link...

http://www.redfin.com/IL/Chicago/401-N-Wabash-Ave-60611/unit-89A/home/40378913

Notice as you start scrolling the menu fixes at the top (I already have this built and working) and by clicking a link in that navigation it automatically scrolls you to the anchor on the page (I have that working as well).  The little red triangle that shows you where you are at is what I would like to do.  Honestly I'm not even sure where to start on figuring this out.  Any suggestions or sample code would be much appreciated. I'll post a mocked up version of the final product here once i get it figured out.

Thanks, J

Comment: Here's someplace to start using jQuery, but you should try some code and add it to your answer.  $(window).scrollTop() will give you a y-scroll value.  $(sectionDiv).offset().top will give you how far down the page each section is.  $(sectionDiv).height() will give the height of that element.  You'll position the arrow with absolute positioning, the rest is mainly doing the correct arithmetic in the onScroll handler.

Answer (score 0):

This will mostly depend on your HTML and how your anchors are located. In my case, I have anchors in the text and hided side menu, that is animated when the anchor is at about the middle of the screen. Here is my code.

```
$('.hiding').each( function(i){
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/2;
        if(bottom_of_window > $(this).position().top && $(this).position().top > 0 ){
            var txt = $(this).children('h1').text();
            $('.sideBar a').each(function() {
                if ($(this).text() == txt){
                    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bolder');
                    $(this).parent().css({
                            'left': '-1em',
                            'background-color': '#FC9',
                            'opacity': '0.6'
                            });
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('font-weight', 'normal');
                        $(this).parent().css({
                            'left': '-2em',
                            'background-color': '#fff',
                            'opacity': '1'
                            });
                        }
                    });
        } 

    });
```

In this code $('.hiding') are your anchors and $('.sideBar a') - your hidden side menu that will show you where you are.